# Get id of checkbox with e.target and <label for="...">

Tags: javascript, html

I try to track the clicks on my website. Therefore I use e.target.id. When clicking on a label with for="mycheckbox" I will get the id of the label, not the checkbox. How can I get the for tag?

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  alert("checkbox with id: " + e.target.id.toString() + " checked"); //doesn't work with labels
, false);
```

Regards

Comment: Shouldn’t it be e.target.getAttribute(“for”) ?

Comment: That's right, vs code didn't liked to show me this option for e.target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `for` attribute by using `e.srcElement.htmlFor` or `e.target.htmlFor`.

P.S. - `for` is not a tag, it is an attribute. You can get value of any attribute by using [getAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp).

Comment: Still wondering why vs code doesn't recognize getAttribute with event.target. Heard that it is not a html element. Anyway, works!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, your `lable` will be the adjacent previous sibling of the input element. In this case, you can use `previousElementSibling.id` to get the id of the `lable`. Below is a snippet explaining the same -

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;  
  //Check if we have clicked on an input -
  if(e.target.outerHTML.includes("input")){
    alert(e.target.previousElementSibling.id);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<lable for="check" id="lable">Check1</lable>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
<br>
<br>
<lable for="check2" id="lable2">Check2</lable>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2">
```

In this way, you can implement the same solutions with multiple inputs.